# Building java project with debugging information using gradle command line

Tags: java, debugging, command-line, build, gradle

Is there a way to have a Gradle project build a java project with debugging information by passing the arguments in the command line?

For example:

```
gradlew assemble <additional args>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What king of arguments do you exactly mean?

Comment: The arguments which are passed in the gradle command line which would allow the java project to be built with debugging information

Comment: If you need to pass any `jvmArgs` you need to it via `compileJava` closure - here are the docs: https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html

Comment: right which is done in the build script, I want to know if it can be done in the command line

Comment: You can pass these arguments via `-P`, `-D` or env variables and read them in gradle script.